# Tabbar customization in ios 4

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios4

I'm working on an iOS application and I need to customize the tabbar to be like this:

[image]
[Tabbar Image](http://postimage.org/image/jxm57t89j/)

A web search gave me this solution:

```
[self.tabBarItem setFinishedSelectedImage:<#(UIImage *)#> withFinishedUnselectedImage:<#(UIImage *)#>]
```

But it is for iOS5. Is there a solution that works in both iOS4 and iOS5?

Comment: see the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10345426/ios-custom-tabbar). it will help.

Answer (score 0):

we use the below code.you can customize the tabbar

```
self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc]init];
firstClassobj.tabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc]
                     initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"yourtext", @"yourtext)
                     image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"your Image"]
                     tag:0];
secondClassobj.tabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc]
                     initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"yourtext", @"yourtext)
                     image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"your Image"]
                     tag:0];
self.tabBarController .viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:firstClassobj,secondClassobj,nil];
```

Comment: you need to initialize the viewcontrollers

Comment: you need to add all view controllers in your array

Comment: i already intialized them
FirstViewController *viewController1 = [[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.firstNav=[[nib instantiateWithOwner:nil options:nil]objectAtIndex:0];
    [self.firstNav setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObject:viewController1]];
self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
self.firstNav.tabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@""
image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tab_btn_members_s0.png"]
                                                    tag:0];

Comment: self.tabBarController.viewControllers = @[self.firstNav, self.secondNav,self.thirdNav,self.fourthNav,self.fifthNav];

Comment: @mohamedkhairy what's the problem in your view ?

Comment: @mohamedkhairy it's works fine.initialise the tabbar controller

Comment: image doesn't appear and tabbar look like this http://postimage.org/image/7suiv9q8j/

Comment: @mohamedkhairy use static images(those are small) and then check

Comment: use this self.tabBarController.tabBar.tintColor=[UIColor redColor];

Comment: what can i do i can;t fix it at all?

Answer (score 0):

//here  is the code  that i implement successfully.......

//in .h set delegate UITabBarControllerDelegate,UITabBarDelegate

```
    UINavigationController *navigationController;
    UITabBarController *tabBarController;
    @property(strong,nonatomic) UINavigationController *navigationController;
    @property(strong,nonatomic) UITabBarController *tabBarController;
```

//in .m

```
  tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
  [tabBarController setDelegate: self];
```

//for tabbar background
      tabBarController.tabBar.tintColor=[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tabbg.png"]];

NSMutableArray *localViewControllersArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:4];

```
Demo1 *home = [[Login alloc] initWithNibName:@"Login" bundle:nil];
    localNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:home];
localNavController.tabBarItem.title=@"demo1";
[localViewControllersArray addObject:localNavController];
    Demo2 *puck=[[Demo2 alloc]initWithNibName:@"Demo2" bundle:nil];
    localNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:puck];
localNavController.tabBarItem.title=@"demo2";
[localViewControllersArray addObject:localNavController];
    Demo3 *photo=[[Demo3 alloc]initWithNibName:@"Demo3" bundle:nil];
    localNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:photo];
localNavController.tabBarItem.title=@"demo3";
    [localViewControllersArray addObject:localNavController];
    Demo4 *more=[[Demo4 alloc]initWithNibName:@"Demo4" bundle:nil];
    localNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:more];
localNavController.tabBarItem.title=@"demo4";
[localViewControllersArray addObject:localNavController];

  [[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:
 [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
  [UIColor grayColor], UITextAttributeTextColor, 
  [UIColor grayColor], UITextAttributeTextShadowColor, 
  [NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(0, 1)], UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset, 
  [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:0.0], UITextAttributeFont, 
  nil] 
                                         forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

//tab bar selected and unselected icons

```
UITabBarItem *tabBarItem1 = [[self.tabBarController.tabBar items] objectAtIndex:0];
[tabBarItem1 setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"puckCentralA.png"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"puckCentral.png"]];
UITabBarItem *tabBarItem2 = [[self.tabBarController.tabBar items] objectAtIndex:1];
[tabBarItem2 setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"puckDisplayA.png"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"puckDisplay.png"]];
UITabBarItem *tabBarItem3 = [[self.tabBarController.tabBar items] objectAtIndex:2];
[tabBarItem3 setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"photoBoothA.png"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"photoBooth.png"]];
UITabBarItem *tabBarItem4 = [[self.tabBarController.tabBar items] objectAtIndex:3];
[tabBarItem4 setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"moreA.png"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"more.png"]];
```

[self.window addSubview:tabBarController.view];