# Tab bar items to have different width

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, custom-controls, uitabbar

I am creating an iPhone app where i need to show 5 tab bar items . My requirement is I want first tab bar item to have smaller width than other 4 . is it possible and how to go about doing this. Please suggest .

Comment: You need to create custom tab bar.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10345426/ios-custom-tabbar

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's possible to do this.  `UITabBar` and `UITabBarItem` are two of the least customizable classes in `UIKit`. `UITabBarItem` does not even inherit from `UIView`.

I needed to something similar and ended up rolling my own `TabBarController`, TabBar and `TabBarItem` classes.  If you only need the basic tab bar functionality it's not too much work.  If you want the fancy new iOS 7 transitions it will be a lot more work.

Answer (score 0):

Please check it out custom tab bar: https://github.com/aalittle/ALCustomTabBarController

In this sample, please go to TabBarView.xib file, you can change all the tabs buttons width and height according to your requirement.

Hope, It will may helpful,

:)

Answer (score -1):

Create a subclass from UITabBarController and write this code in viewDidLoad.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

[self addCustomElements];

}

-(void)addCustomElements
{
 // Backgroun
UIImageView* bgView = Your backgroun image for tab bar;
bgView.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height-50, 320, 50);




[self.view addSubview:bgView];



// Initialise our two images
UIImage *btnImage = default image for your tab item;
UIImage *btnImageSelected = selected image for your tab item;

tab1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom]; //Setup the button
tab1.frame = // Set the frame (size and position) of the button)
[tab1 setImage:btnImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
  [btnMore setBackgroundImage:btnImageSelected forState:UIControlStateSelected];
[tab1 setTitle:@"title for 1st button" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[tab1 setTag:0];

// Add my new buttons to the view
[self.view addSubview:tab1];


//repeat same for remaining button

// Setup event handlers so that the buttonClicked method will respond to the touch up inside event.
[tab1 addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];




 }
```

set this subclass to your tab bar controller.