# Is there way to customize TabBar like this?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5

Is there way to customize TabBar like this?
We use iOS5.

[image]

Comment: You could certainly roll your own.

Comment: @qegal but if we will put own bar we well need to develop own navigation controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this isn't actually to difficult to do.

1) Subclass UITTabBarController

2) Run a method to hide all UITabBar class elements like below

3) Draw your own elements onto self ([self.view addSubview:CustomButton])

```
for(UIView *subview in self.view.subviews) {
    if([subview isKindOfClass:[UITabBar class]]) {
        subview.hidden = YES;
        break;
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

As a further update to explain how your image example is done.  You have 4 elements:
1) Background image
2) Left button
3) Middle button
4) Right button

So UIImageView and UIButton with [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom] are all you need for this magic to happen.

Answer (score 1):

you can get a better idea on the customization using [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/4344/user-interface-customization-in-ios-5)

Answer (score 0):

Check here [how can i create custom tab bar ...add custom images in tab bar (without xib changes)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4710298/how-can-i-create-custom-tab-bar-add-custom-images-in-tab-bar-without-xib-cha)

Don't forget Tab Bar consists of rectangular tabs - your design does not really follow these rules...

So, I am not sure if this will pass Apple's UI guidelines when submitting to App store

Why not make a NavigationBar that looks like this?