# Creating a Custom Tabbar

Tags: objective-c, ios, tabs, uitabbarcontroller

I'm trying to create a custom tabbar, it has 3 tabs on the bottom of the screen.
I want to have a view (it size 320x40) on the top of the screens. Each tab always appear in this view.
How can I do this?
Thanks,

Comment: Seems like you could just use the `UITabBarController` with 3 tabs. Why do you need a custom one ?

Comment: I set myself the images and titles of the tabbars. Can I do this without using custom tabbar?

Comment: yes ! you can do it without a custom one.

Answer (score 2):

I used one of the several from the link below, since I didn't have enough time to write my own. Pretty decent implementation.

[Custom TabBar Control](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=tabbar)

Comment: you dont need a custom tab bar for this.

Answer (score 0):

Please fine the below links

http://kurrytran.blogspot.in/2011/10/ios-5-tutorial-creating-custom-tab-bar.html

[how can i create custom tab bar ...add custom images in tab bar (without xib changes)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4710298/how-can-i-create-custom-tab-bar-add-custom-images-in-tab-bar-without-xib-cha)

Both of them are good to teach U.. Hope this one helps :)

Comment: you dont need a custom tab bar for this.